# What does it mean - "end of sorts"?

Tags: meaning

> And it is also clear that the war is, as all wars do, moving toward an
>   **end of sorts**.
>
> Source: "The Next 100 Years" by George Friedman

What does it mean - "end of sorts" ?

Comment: _X of sorts_ means _a kind of X_. It implies that it was not really an X as you would expect an X to be. _He was a friend of sorts_ means he was not a real friend, _an end of sorts_ implies that it was not really the end of that war, but something that looked like it. A bit like Churchill said: this is not the beginning of the end, it is merely the end of the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

From Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**of a sort**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of-a-sort)
>   (also **of sorts**)
>   *informal* Of a somewhat unusual or inferior kind:
>   "*the training camp actually became a tourist attraction of sorts*"

This is roughly the same as what @oerkelens said. The full context for your quote is as follows:

> The American Age began in December 1991, when the Soviet Union collapsed, leaving the United States as the only global power in the world. But the twenty-first century truly began on September 11, 2001, ten years later, when planes slammed into the World Trade Center and the Pentagon. This was the first real test of the American Age. It is debatable whether the United States has actually won the war, but it has certainly achieved its strategic goals. **And it is also clear that the war is, as all wars do, moving toward *an end of sorts*.** People talk about the long war, and the idea that the United States and Muslims will be fighting for a century.
>
> *The Next 100 Years: A Forecast for the 21st Century*, 2009 © George Friedman

In this particular case, it's making reference to the the Iraq Wars and the wars in Afghanistan. Soldiers were being withdrawn from these locations, even though there is still some ongoing conflict. As there is ongoing conflict, the end of these wars is not what you might first think will happen at the end of a war (such as peace, the arresting and prosecution of opposing forces, and so on).